# Resetting the UP-TO-DATE property of gradle tasks?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is there a way I can force a gradle task to run again, or reset *all* tasks back to the not UP-TO-DATE state?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Try to run your build with `-C rebuild` that rebuilds Gradle's cache.

In newer versions of Gradle, use `--rerun-tasks`

Answer (score 98):

If you want just a single task to always run, you can set the `outputs` property inside of the task.

```
outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

Please be aware that if your task does not have any defined file inputs, Gradle may skip the task, even when using the above code. For example, in a Zip or Copy task there needs to be at least one file provided in the **configuration** phase of the task definition.

Comment: This does nothing for me. I added it to a task and get "UP-TO-DATE". The funny thing is that it's a ZipTask and I deleted the destination archive.

Comment: This is incredible for usage like this: `tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
            if (theTask.name.startsWith("dex")) {
                theTask.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                theTask.doLast { task ->... }}}`

Comment: Updated answer for case when task will not run.

Comment: Beware that nowadays when the gradle built cache is enabled this will not cause the task to run again, but its output will just be restored from cache.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `cleanTaskname`

Let's say you have

```
:someproject:sometask1 UP-TO-DATE
:someproject:sometask2 UP-TO-DATE
:someproject:sometask3 UP-TO-DATE
```

And you want to force let's say sometask2 to run again you can

```
someproject:cleanSometask2
```

before you run the task that runs it all.

Apparently in gradle, every task that understands UP-TO-DATE also understand how to clean itself.

Comment: 'gradle clean' will clean everything for the project you are in. It basically deletes your main output folder which is '/build' by default. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No. That won't re-set up-to-date if up-to-date was captured as no output files for a given task. That is, if I had some part of the build break but succeed overall, the captured state is wrong, and I need to clear it.

Comment: normally the 'clean' task that deletes everyting in $buildDir is available in build scripts as it is introduced by the base plugin.

Answer (score 6):

I had a tough case where setting `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }` inside the task or adding the flag `--rerun-tasks` didn't help since the task's `setOnlyIf` kept being set to `false` each time I ran it.

Adding the following to `build.gradle` forced the execution of `myTask`:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
  def tasks = taskGraph.getAllTasks()
  tasks.each {
    def taskName = it.getName()
    if(taskName == 'myTask') {
      println("Found $taskName")

      it.setOnlyIf { true }
      it.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```bash
./gradlew clean
```

It will force the gradle to rebuild.

Comment: @toolforger Yes, it seems they removed it. So you have to run `./gradlew clean`