# Crashlytics doesn't symbolicate android crashlogs

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm using crashlytics-ndk with gradle plugin in my application.

When I run `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease --info --debug` it writes me that crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease is skipped:

```
20:08:16.488 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease
20:08:16.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease'
20:08:16.488 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Putting task artifact state for task ':crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease' into context took 0.0 secs.
20:08:16.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease' is up-to-date
20:08:16.488 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskTypeTaskStateChanges] Task :crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease class loader hash: 7064e588920e76a48571db060884e368
20:08:16.488 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskTypeTaskStateChanges] Task :crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease actions class loader hash: 9d5b3601aafc02f324fe4d7eca81c860
20:08:16.489 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).
20:08:16.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
20:08:16.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease'
20:08:16.490 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease UP-TO-DATE
20:08:16.490 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 12,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
```

I even don't remember, did I see any other execution result. 
By the way, all my crashlogs looks like this one:

[image: Crashlog without symbols]

I have cSym files after build:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -lA build/fabric/*/*
build/fabric/debug/csyms:
total 82736
-rw-r--r--  1 vasya  staff  42360506 11 дек 19:51 godot_android-armv7-82196e26bb0953d61b033487c4f485860e1f0e5c.cSYM

build/fabric/release/csyms:
total 82736
-rw-r--r--  1 vasya  staff  42360506 11 дек 19:47 godot_android-armv7-82196e26bb0953d61b033487c4f485860e1f0e5c.cSYM
```

But I have no idea how can I upload them to crashlytics manually.

Is there a way to check uploading status in crashlytics, or how can I check uploading in crashlytics gradle plugin?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Crashlytics and Crashlytics NDK? 2.8.0 for Crashlytics and 2.0.1 for NDK.

Comment: yes

`compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') { transitive = true; }`

`compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.1@aar')`

Comment: Also I added this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422984/2764408
Now `crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` performs every time. But symbols in crashlogs still missed.

Comment: Can you write into support@fabric.io about this? There're a few things we can check but it requires sharing logs and crash URLs, so it's not easy to debug on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have wrote to support@fabric.io yesterday and still have no any answer. Very sad.

Comment: I'll have the team look into it!

Comment: I've just noticed that file `assets/crashlytics-build.properties` in my apk has `package_name=com.godot.game`

But apk has package name `free.line.games.match.three.puzzle.galaxy.adventure.android`

Could this difference lead to the issue with missed symbols?

Comment: @Alexizamerican Still no answer from support. By the way, could I check something on my side? May be there is a way to enable more debug output for fabric gradle plugin?

Comment: I'll ping the team again. I know they're working hard through the support queue and will answer soon.

Comment: @Alexizamerican thank you!

Comment: did u solve your problem? please share the solution. I have the same issue.